# Analysis of customer along time

Tags: sql, sorting, datetime, group-by

I have the task of developing a SQL query for analysing the behaviour of a customer through time.

So, I started with two tables; a calendar table (with each year-month-day of some years), and a sales table (with an ID and a purchase date of my interest) This is the query:

```
SELECT [Spice Id], FORMAT([Fecha venta],'yyyyMM') AS Purchase_Date
INTO #Sale_date
FROM SALES
WHERE [Spice Id] IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY [Spice Id], [Fecha venta]
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bSxEb.jpg) and [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/okVhd.jpg)

Then I use a cross join to have all dates available even though the customer has no purchase in dates, I use a where clause to limit the table as I want to. Query below

```
SELECT [Spice Id], year, YearMonth, Purchase_Date, (Purchase_Date) AS First_purchase, (Purchase_Date) AS Last_purchase
INTO #Sorted
FROM #calendar 
CROSS JOIN #Sale_date
WHERE year > 2019 
  AND Purchase_Date > 202001 
  AND Purchase_Date < FORMAT(GETDATE(),'yyyyMM') 
  AND YearMonth BETWEEN purchase_date AND FORMAT(GETDATE(), 'yyyyMM')
GROUP BY
    [Spice Id], Year, YearMonth, Purchase_Date 
ORDER BY
    [Spice Id], Year ASC, YearMonth, Purchase_date
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vC8mq.jpg)

Then as you can see first purchase and lastpurchase are just the same as purchase date, so I update both values with the following:

----------UPDATE MIN

```
UPDATE #Sorted
enter code here`SET #SORTED.First_purchase = t1.minimo
FROM #Sorted
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT [SPICE ID],MIN([First_purchase]) AS minimo
FROM #Sorted
GROUP BY [Spice Id])
AS t1 on t1.[spice id] = #Sorted.[spice id]
```

--------------Update Max

```
UPDATE #Sorted
SET #SORTED.Last_purchase = t1.maximo
FROM #SORTED
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT [SPICE ID],MAX([Last_purchase]) AS maximo
FROM #Sorted
where Purchase_Date <= YearMonth
GROUP BY [Spice Id])
AS t1 on t1.[spice id] = #Sorted.[spice id]
```

So once I updated both values I got the following result, I'll use a specific ID to be more clear:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ttEqi.jpg)

AS you can see, I have some mistakes Purchase_Date is not correctly ordered, I really don't mind that much because i can drop that column and leave just Start and Last, my big trouble is with last purchase, it should change overtime and update as in the following example I don't know if you find any mistakes in my logic or a better way to get to it, I wish to see the final table as this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y8V27.png)

I hope it is clear enough, thank you very much for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure your desired output but the updating logic to get the first and last purchase date is entirely unneccessary. You can use something like the below to always obtain these values

```
min(Purchase_date) over (partition by spice_id) as first_purchase
max(Purchase_date) over (partition by spice_id) as last_purchase
```

If you wish for purchase date to be ordered correctly then you need to evalute your order by clause, since this is last in the clause it is ordered after the first several columns have been ordered